# How i can apply animation on menu when i press the humberger menu

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu for a responsive page i toggle it and it works, I want that when I click on the hamburger menu the menu shows up but with smooth animations,

I tried to put animations properties on the menu in my CSS but it didn't work

```
  <header> 
    <div class="toggle"><img src="./Images/menu.png" alt="#"></div>
    <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="main-menu active">
                    <li><a href="#0.1_">Maçon </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0.1_">Menuisier</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0.1_">Peintre </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#0.1_">Carreleur </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0.1_">Plombier </a></li>
                  </ul>
            </nav>
    
    </header>


//CSS

.main-nav > ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 36px 100px;
    top: -64px;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin-top: 10px;
}


 /*The menu for responsive */
    
    .main-nav .main-menu.active {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0,0,0.95);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: why color to transition?

Comment: I just remove it but still transition didn't work on my menu